# Radio button on select navigation to URL

Tags: javascript, html

I am newbie to java script and trying to achieve the following and was looking for suggestions:

Create two radio buttons and whenever we select on radio button it should navigate to some URL like in the below example XYZ.com or ABC.com

```
<html>
<table width="450">
<tr>
<td style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"><h4>Choose a Field</h4></td>
</tr>
</table></br>
<form action="../">
<fieldset>
<input type="RADIO" value="http://xyz.com"     name="userChoice" id="navRadio01">
 <label for="navRadio01">XYZ</label><br> 
<input type="RADIO" value="http://abc.com"    name="userChoice" id="navRadio02" checked>
        <label for="navRadio02">ABC</label><br>  
<input type="BUTTON"  value="Go"    onclick="ob=this.form.userChoice;for(i=0;i<ob.length;i++){
    if(ob[i].checked){window.open(ob[i].value,'_self');};}" style="color:#FFFFF;background-color:#E0E0E5;font-family:verdana;border-style:solid;" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</html>
```

I have used the Go button in the above example how can we do this, without using the Go button and once selected navigate to that link.?

Please advice.

Thank you all in advance.

-
V

Comment: Why do you want to use radio buttons and not anchor tags, which are more semantically correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here:

[Calling onclick on a radiobutton list using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362614/calling-onclick-on-a-radiobutton-list-using-javascript)

There's a bit of a debate and then a full example at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using the "onclick" event handler for radio buttons, like this:

```
<input type="RADIO" value="http://abc.com" onclick="window.open(this.value)" name="userChoice" id="navRadio02" checked>
```

Please note that as stated in the comments to your question, anchor tags are better suited to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```
<html>
<table width="450">
<tr>
<td style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"><h4>Choose a Field</h4></td>
</tr>
</table></br>
<form action="../">
<fieldset>
<input type="RADIO" name="userChoice" id="navRadio01" onclick="window.location='http://google.com'">
<input type="RADIO" name="userChoice" id="navRadio02"  onclick="window.location='http://yahoo.com.com'">
</fieldset>
</form>
</html>
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: This is the correct answer; it navigates to the new url using the current window, the other implementations open the url in a new window/tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a reference of the radio button to a function triggered by the radio button's onclick event. Then within the function, you open the link specified by the radio button's value.

For example, function `openLink` opens a link based upon the radio button's value.

```
<script>
function openLink(radio){
 window.open(radio.value,'_self');
}
</script>
```

Then in the body of the HTML page, you pass a reference to the radio button when it is clicked, to function `openLink`:

```
<fieldset>
<input type="radio" id="fname"  value="http://www.abc.com" name="name1" onclick="openLink(this)">

<input type="radio" value="http://www.xyz.com" id="fname2" name="name1" onclick="openLink(this)">
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<table width="450">
<tr>
<td style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"><h4>Choose a Field</h4></td>
</tr>
</table></br>
<form action="../">
<fieldset>
<input type="RADIO" name="userChoice" id="navRadio01" onclick="window.location='http://google.com'">
<input type="RADIO" name="userChoice" id="navRadio02"  onclick="window.location='http://yahoo.com.com'">
</fieldset>
</form>
</html>
```