# toggle div visiblity using prototype.js

Tags: html, prototypejs

I'd this html code:

```
<li>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="payment[ebzc_option]" value="saved" />Saved</label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <select name="payment[ebzc_method_id]">
            <option value="">Please select...</option>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="payment[ebzc_option]" value="saved" />New</label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <select name="payment[ebzc_method_id]">
            <option value="">Please select...</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
            <option value="4">Four</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
```

and I need to toggle the `<div class="input-box">` adjacent to the **checked radio** (`name="payment[ebzc_option]"`) button using `prototype`.

Can anybody help me to do this? I'd not worked on `prototype` before.
any hint on selecting radio button by name attribute (`name="payment[ebzc_option]"`) in `prototype.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a function that you can call both at page load and whenever a radio button is clicked.

```
function setSubmenuVisibility(){
  $$('input[type="radio"]').each(function(elm){
    if(elm.up('label') && elm.up('label').next('div')){
      var sub = elm.up('label').next('div');
      if(elm.checked){
        sub.show();
      }else{
        sub.hide();
      }
     }
   });
 }
 setSubmenuVisibility();
 document.on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function(evt, elm){
   setSubmenuVisibility();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the visibility using [**Element.toggle**](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Element/toggle/)

Comment: but I've to do it only on change of selection of radio button. How do I add an observer on those radio buttons?

Comment: I'm really sorry to say that I cannot use jquery here

Comment: Then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362614/calling-onclick-on-a-radiobutton-list-using-javascript

Comment: any hint on selecting radio button by name attribute (`name="payment[ebzc_option]"`) in prototype.js? I tried `$$('[name="payment[ebzc_option]"]')` but getting error in console

Comment: The documentation suggests using [**$**](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/dollar/index.html)

Comment: `$$('[name="payment[ebzc_option]"]')` is returning an array. How can I get the element object from it?

Comment: Try using $('payment[ebzc_option]')

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48482/discussion-between-mohammad-faisal-and-jpo)

Comment: As we discussed in chat, and for anyone reading this, having multiple elements with the same id is not a good idea, and will cause problems when using selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this

<strike>you could use the DOM traversal methods if the HTML will be the same</strike>

```
$$('input[name="payment[ebzc_option]"]').invoke('observe','click',function(){
    this.nextSiblings().first().toggle();
});
```

In this instance we use `$$()` to select all of the radio buttons with the name attribute `payment[ebzc_option]` and use the `invoke()` method to call `observe()` on all of them. In the closure of the event handler `this` is the element the event happened on, then you collect all of the next siblings using `nextSiblings()`, pick the `first()` one out of the array and run `toggle()` on it.

This is not ideal because it depends on the HTML structure to stay the same.

Lets try adding an id to the divs you want to toggle (ids need to be unique like you discovered), and lets add that id to the radio button in a data attribute. Data attributes can be anything you want just need to start with `data-`

```
<div class="input-box" id="input-box_saved">

<input type="radio" name="payment[ebzc_option]" value="saved" data-toggle="input-box_saved" />
```

Now our observer statement changes to

```
$$('input[name="payment[ebzc_option]"]').invoke('observe','click',function(){
    $(this.readAttribute('data-toggle')).toggle();
});
```

you could even extend the observer closure to make sure only one of the divs is open at a time

```
$$('input[name="payment[ebzc_option]"]').invoke('observe','click',function(){

    $$('.input-box').invoke('hide');

    $(this.readAttribute('data-toggle')).show();
});
```

**EDIT** I missed that the `<input>` and `<div>` were not siblings as the closing `</label>` was going off the right side of the box. In this instance the DOM traversal would be a bit more `up()` and `down()` to get it to work.

Comment: I'd created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2H5eU/) but your first solution is not working?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal Ah yes the radio input tag is inside the label tag, which would make the label and div tag siblings. That becomes a bit more problematic then - I'll adjust my answer.