# wordpress contact form 7 plugin enable section if option selected on other

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

i'm trying to create a post that displays some radio button only if "YES" is selected on other radio buttons...

I don't really know how to do this.
Any idea someone?

thanks

Comment: Use a javascript `onclick` handler to change the visibility or create/destroy the other objects on the page. See here for examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362614/calling-onclick-on-a-radiobutton-list-using-javascript