# Silex: redirect onchange select button (using URL Generator)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, select, silex

I'm using the Silex Framework. I'm creating a system where users can answer my questions. And I've got the following route set up:

```
$routes->match('/assignment/register/{type}/{count}', function (Request $request, $type, $count) use ($app) {
```

Now, there can be two types of questions: Multiple Choice or Open. The type of the route is either MC or OP. So, the form will be generated like this:

```
if($type == 'MC'){

        $builder->add('type', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Type',
            'required' => 'required',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'select-field', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'onchange' => 'this.form.submit()'),
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'label'),
            'choices' => array('Multiple Choice' => 'MC', 'Open' => 'OP'),
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => false,
        ));

    }
    if($type == 'OP'){

        $builder->add('type', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Type',
            'required' => 'required',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'select-field', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'onchange' => 'this.form.submit()'),
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'label'),
            'choices' => array('Multiple Choice' => 'MC', 'Open' => 'OP'),
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => false,
            'data' => 'OP',
        ));

    }
```

However, I want to be redirected when I choose for another type of question. So let's say I'm on the MC question, how can I be redirected to the OP page when I select OP in the select box? I thought something should be done with `onchange=''`. But I have no clue on how to continue.

### Update

When I change the select button I 'd like to be redirected to the New URL:

Let's say I'm on the multiple choice page:

> Www.MyWebsite.nl/Escape/public/assignment/create/MC/3

MC stands for multiple choice, and the 3 tells the script that I can give 3 answers.

Now when I set the select to Open Question (OP) I need to be redirected to this URL:

> Www.MyWebsite.nl/Escape/public/assignment/create/OP/1

This has to be done using the URL generator in Silex/Symfony, because I can't just give the full URL

### update 2

I've now got the following piece of code in my twig template. However, it still doesn't execute when I change my select box:

```
{% block scripts %}
    {% if urlTo is defined %}
          <script>
          var urlTo = {{ urlTo }}; 
          document.getElementById('form_type').onchange(function()
          {
            alert(urlTo);
            window.location.href(urlTo);
          });
        </script>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

The URL is given perfectly. I've tested that, so that part does work. Where is my mistake?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... When you say redirect you mean full page reload? Or you want an AJAX call to dinamically change the question? Can you elaborate on your use case?

Comment: I've updated my question, I hope this helps you

Comment: To do the redirect you have to do it in Javascript because that will be client code run on the browser. But you have the problem of where to redirect to. You have basically 2 options. Generate the URL in your controller and pass it to your template or if you are using twig you have the [path/url functions](https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/1.3/providers/url_generator.html#usage). Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362614/calling-onclick-on-a-radiobutton-list-using-javascript) which may help you with the JS code.

Comment: so can you please give me an answer on how to pass the generated URL from the controller to the script (which I don't know how to write) from the Onchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass the URL from the controller to your script you just need to attach a template variable like so:

```
<?php
// somwhere in your route definition file
$app->match(
    '/assignment/register/{type}/{count}', 
    function (Request $request, $type, $count) use ($app) {
      // do your magic here
      $urlTo = $app['url_generator']->generate('path-name', [$path=>$options]);

      // here you pass the $urlTo variable to your template
      // by passing a 2n argument to the render method
      // https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/providers/twig.html#usage
      return $app['twig']->render('your-template-name-here.twig', ["urlTo" => $urlTo]);
    }
);
```

And then in your template where you define your JS (assuming you are using Twig, you have not specified on which templating are you using):

```
<?php
// this is your template file
<script>
  var urlTo = {{ urlTo }}; // here comes the injection from the PHP value to JS
  document.getElementById('the-id-of-the-select-element').onchange = function(e) {
    // probably you want to check the selected value here and then...
    window.location.replace(urlTo);
  };
</script>
```

This is a bare minimum skeleton to show how to pass the urlTo PHP variable into your template and convert it into a JS variable. From here on, you should elaborate on that and adapt this code to your use case.

Comment: does onclick work for a select box? (It isn't a radio button)

Comment: P.s. yes I'm using twig

Comment: I've updated my question again, I still seem to do something wrong again

Comment: Yes, the onclic event handler should work on a select box also (on practically any HTML element BTW). If you are using a select box, you should use the [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) instead (I've updated the code)

Comment: I've tried it again, but for some reason, still nothing happens, not even a page reload... and in addition: what does the e in function(e) do?

Comment: the e parameter represents the [Event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), but this is OT. By the way, the code was not working as the ```onchange``` is not a method call but a property, so it has to be assigned (see edit). My bad!