# javascript radio on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would know how to update a file when I click on radio button
When I click on the radio button, the page is updated with the new radio button checked.

I added :

```
id="radio_shipping_' . $j .'"
```

Now I miss the javascript. I don't know how to

Thank you

```
for ($j=0, $n2=count($quote['methods']); $j<$n2; $j++) {
  $checked = (($quote['id'] . '_' . $quote['methods'][$j]['id'] == $_SESSION['shipping']['id']) ? true : false);

  $data .= '<tr>';
  $data .= '<td class="text-md-right">';

  if (isset($quotes['error'])) {
    $data .= '&nbsp;';
  } else {
    $data .=  '<span class="moduleRadio">'  . HTML::radioField('shipping', $quote['id'] . '_' . $quote['methods'][$j]['id'], $checked, 'required aria-required="true" id="radio_shipping_' . $j .'"') .'</span>';
  }

  $data .= '</td>';
  $data .= '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: @B001ᛦWhen I click on the radio , the page is updated with the new radio button checked.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362614/calling-onclick-on-a-radiobutton-list-using-javascript This should help Good luck :)