# Loop function not running after WooCommerce cart page update

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to run a simple loop on the WooCommerce cart page.
When the page initially loads, the function does it's thing, but on update of the cart, it becomes lifeless.

Here's my loop function:

```
let radios = document.querySelectorAll( 'input[name="radio_options_set"]' );

simplySetAttrs();

function simplySetAttrs() {

    // I started the var at 1 to skip the first radio input
    for (var xx = 1; xx < radios.length; xx++) {
        radios[xx].setAttribute( 'onclick', 'dothisFunction( this );' );
    }
}
```

The only WooCommerce event that has shown any response is *'updated_cart_totals'* and the radio buttons I'm targeting on the Cart page are inserted by another plugin.

Here's how I implemented it:

```
jQuery( document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', simplySetAttrs() );
```

I can't get to figure out why the very basic loop doesn't take action. If I do an alert(), it works as expected, even after setting a timeout on it.

I've also tried adding different event listeners as an alternative to setting the attributes, but to no avail.

Comment: Try to console `radios` and check if you get any.

Comment: Can it be you used the setAttribute wrong? Look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/362634/11592836

Comment: @Bhautik - Yes, the Nodelist of  `radios`  does get logged.

Comment: can you share the site URL?

Comment: Here it is: [link](https://mysub.ng/) @Bhautik

Comment: where is `radio_options_set` radio in cart page?

Comment: Oh, sorry... The code I used in the question is just for demo. Here's the actual variable: `let sub_Rdios = document.querySelectorAll( 'input[name="convert_to_sub"]' )` @Bhautik

Comment: @Allart - I found a way forward from the link you sent and combined it with the answer to my question. It was the explanation given in this answer: 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378424/9633096). Thanks.

Comment: Glad to be of help :). I see @Bhautik kinda went awey with my answer, but hey, it is what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery `attr` to setAttribute. Try the below code.

```
let radios = document.querySelectorAll( 'input[name="convert_to_sub"]' );

simplySetAttrs();

function simplySetAttrs() {
    // I started the var at 1 to skip the first radio input
    for (var xx = 1; xx < radios.length; xx++) {
        jQuery(radios[xx]).attr( 'onclick', 'dothisFunction( this );' );
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the jQuery `attr` approach and still had the same behavior initially - But this answer mentioned something that I tried out: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378424/9633096) - I set the `attr` on each radio's parent `li` and everything came alive.
I'll rework my code by referencing the `li` items.
Thanks a whole bunch for helping to create another direction.